Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "auth-depl" not found
I am learning a microservices course from udemy and when the professor said to push the code to GitHub I got, on GitHub, on this command:
kubectl rollout restart deployment auth-depl

I got this error:
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "auth-depl" not found


On GitHub, following the professor instructions, I created yaml files, for each service to run everytime when I push the code or I have a pull request. So pushing the code I will see inside Actions tab, from GitHub, the result that I put it in the screenshot.
As you can see in the screenshot I have that command inside of deploy-auth.yaml file, that has all these commands:
name: deploy-auth

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'auth/**'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: docker login -u $DOCKER_USERNAME -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
        env:
          DOCKER_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
      - run: cd auth && docker build -t my_docker_name/auth .
      - run: docker push my_docker_name/auth
      - uses: digitalocean/action-doctl@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      - run: doctl kubernetes cluster kubeconfig save ticketing
      - run: kubectl rollout restart deployment auth-depl

I am on the right context running:
kubectl config current-context

I got
do-fra1-ticketing

I implemented Ingress NGINX on microservices, for this Digital Ocean context, using this:
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.11.2/deploy/static/provider/do/deploy.yaml

And this is the auth-depl.yaml file, for what I got the above error. File that is inside k8s folder.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: my_docker_name/auth
          env:
            - name: MONGO_URI
              value: 'mongodb://auth-mongo-srv:27017/auth'
            - name: JWT_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jtw-secret
                  key: JWT_KEY

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000


I run the project localy on a windows laptop.
I searched a lot and I didn't find the solution, because auth-depl.yaml file exists.
Can anyone help me please?

Is the application deployed into the default namespace, or somewhere else?  You have separate Kubernetes client configurations in your local environment and the CI environment; do either of these name alternate namespaces?

David I don't know how to answer to this. I guess into the defaul namespace. In the course didn't mention about default on not. If I run kubectl get namespace I get NAME              STATUS   AGE default           Active   9d ingress-nginx     Active   145m kube-node-lease   Active   9d kube-public       Active   9d kube-system       Active   9d

I'd also suggest here that kubectl rollout restart probably isn't the tool you want.  Your CI pipeline should assign a new tag per build, and then it needs to feed that tag into the Kubernetes manifests (Helm, Customize, Carvel kbld can all do this).  Then you kubectl apply the (updated) manifest, which will work regardless of whether the service has been installed already or not.  This also makes it possible to roll back to an older build.

On the course, for the professon, this  kubectl rollout restart deployment aut-depl worked. In the past I got a different error on this command: E0930 09:06:09.731184    1798 memcache.go:265] "Unhandled Error" err="couldn't get current server API group list: Get \"http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s\": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused", but I deleted ingress-nginx with a kubectl delete namespace ingress-nginx and ran again  kubectl apply -f .... for install ingress. So now I am in this point, with this error, that I describe it in the question.

We need say to Deployment to use the latest version. And with this kubectl rollout restart deployment auth-depl we wil update the auth Deployment,  inside
Auth Service, with the latest changes that I made.

The idiomatic way to use the most recent image is to change the Deployment's image: to a newer image.  A date stamp or source-control ID often works as a good tag; for example, if you use my_docker_name/auth:20240930, then kubectl apply will delete the old Pods and recreate them, and you can switch back to ...:20240927 if there turns out to be a problem with the new build.

Like I said David, please don't get me wrong, but I follow a tutorial on udemy. It is the first time when I interact with microservices. If you have better solution, then the professor did, please provide it with great details.
